# Find the limit: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|x|^{n} - (1 + |x|^2)^{\frac{2}{n}}}{(1 + |x|^2)^{\frac{2}{n}}}.$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

How to find the limit: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|x|^{n} - (1 + |x|^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(1 + |x|^2)^{\frac{n}{2}}}.$$
where $1<n<2$ and $x \in \mathbb R^d$.
It seems the limit is 0 by using rationalization (conjugation), but how to deal with the numerator after multiplying the conjugate term?

Update on the range of $n$:
Thanks for the comment below and I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: For $n\geq3$ the $|x|^n$ term dominates and the limit diverges.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why do you think that's absolute value sign?

Comment: What does $x\to\infty$ mean for $x\in\mathbf{R}^d?$  Do all the coordinates go to $\infty$ or is one enough?

Comment: Could you show what you have done so far?

Comment: Focus on $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|x|^{n}}{(1 + |x|^2)^{\frac{2n}{n2}}}.$$

Comment: The title has exponents $2\over n$; the text has them as $n\over2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=1+|x|^2$, so that $|x|^n=(u-1)^{n/2}$. We have

$${|x|^n-(1+|x|^2)^{n/2}\over(1+|x|^2)^{n/2}}={(u-1)^{n/2}-u^{n/2}\over u^{n/2}}=\left(1-{1\over u}\right)^{n/2}-1\to1-1=0$$

since $u\to\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$.